# In hadoop,how to get last element in values

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Here's some input data in .csv for example:

- url1 a
- url2 b
- url3 c
- url4 d
- url5 e
- url1 k
- url1 h
- url2 x
- url5 m

And what I want is:

- url1 h
- url2 x
- url3 c
- url4 d
- url5 m

to output,
but what I got is:

- url1 a
- url2 b
- url3 c
- url4 d
- url5 e

I dont know what's wrong with my code,and here's some code of my program:

function map:

```
 public class MergeUrlMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    String valueString = value.toString();
    String[] UrlHtmlData = valueString.split(",");
    output.collect(new Text(UrlHtmlData[0]), new Text(UrlHtmlData[1]));
}
}
```

and function reduce:

```
public class MergeUrlReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
public void reduce(Text t_key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    Text key = t_key;
    // if values is empty,then output will be (t_key,t_key)
    Text latestHtml = t_key;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        Text temp = values.next();
        latestHtml = temp;
    }
    output.collect(key, latestHtml);
}
}
```

What's wrong with my code,output supposed to be the last value,but in fact it is the first value. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the values isn't guaranteed.

If you want to sort them according to some order, you'll need to add all iterator values into an Arraylist, then call `Collections.sort` on it using a custom Comparator, if you want.

Then get element at `list.size() - 1`

---

Also, your input contains no commas according to your question, so make sure you are splitting on the correct character.

Comment: oh,yeah,thanks for reminding me that the order of the values isnt guaranteed,I didnt thought about that.As for no commas problem,as I mentioned in problem description,I put the input data in .csv,so that's not a problem.Thanks a lot,dude.

Comment: My point was that `url1 a` has no commas... CSV extension doesn't matter